# I want to display the button vertically with microsoft teams

Tags: node.js, office365, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a bot to use with microsoftteams. I am using the button to display the answer options, but if I check with ios or Android it will be displayed side by side. Is there any way to display buttons vertically?

```
for(var i= 0; i< arrayList.length; i++ ){
  var val = arrayList[i].choice;
  buttons.push(builder.CardAction.imBack(session, val, val));
}                      
var card = new builder.HeroCard(session).buttons(buttons);
var msg = new builder.Message(session).addAttachment(card);
builder.Prompts.text(session, msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately right now you can't control the layout of the buttons on a card.

Do you mind adding this as a suggestion on [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public), with examples of why this level of control would be useful, so others can vote on your idea?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it not possible to display the button vertically even if "Prompts.choice()" is used instead of the card?

Comment: No, only cards can contain buttons, so Prompts.choice() will show a card anyway. The suggestion below to use adaptive cards is probably your best bet, once adaptive cards are supported in the Teams mobile clients.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

While unfortunately hero cards are bound to the layouts given by their respective channels/viewing devices (ie why you get different views on Teams vs iOS), adaptive cards will allow for greater formatting of layout. At this time however, adaptive cards are not available on Microsoft Teams.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it not possible to display the button vertically even if "Prompts.choice()" is used instead of the card?